# Http-server nodejs running but not working

Tags: node.js, httpserver

I am trying to run http-server for nodejs.

After using `npm start` the server starts on the given port(8000) perfectly with a few ignorable errors. But when I try to run the application url, it says 'Webpage is not available'.
When i tried to `ping` the IP it responds by sending packets perfectly.

When I run `http-server` command it shows that it is running on 127.0.0.1:8080 and 172.31.46.121:8080. I tried changing the localhost port to 8080,but with no difference in results.

I am using putty client to run linux on windows.

**nodejs version**-5.4.1

**npm version**-3.7.0

Please help..

There is one more thing..

I ran this server on putty at port 80. Then with the server still running i tried to run the same nodejs server using Bitnami client(i.e. using `npm start`) at the same port(80) and **there was no conflict of ports**. Even the app is running fine at that port when I run it through Bitnami client.

http-server file code-

```
` #!/usr/bin/env node

var colors = require('colors'),
httpServer = require('../lib/http-server'),
argv = require('optimist').argv,
portfinder = require('portfinder'),
opener = require('opener');

if (argv.h || argv.help) {
console.log([
"usage: http-server [path] [options]",
"",
"options:",
"  -p                 Port to use [8080]",
"  -a                 Address to use [0.0.0.0]",
"  -d                 Show directory listings [true]",
"  -i                 Display autoIndex [true]",
"  -e --ext           Default file extension if none supplied [none]",
"  -s --silent        Suppress log messages from output",
"  --cors             Enable CORS via the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'       header",
"  -o                 Open browser window after staring the server",
"  -c                 Set cache time (in seconds). e.g. -c10 for 10 seconds.",
"                     To disable caching, use -c-1.",
"  -h --help          Print this list and exit."
 ].join('\n'));
process.exit();
}

var port = argv.p || parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10),
host = argv.a || '0.0.0.0',
log = (argv.s || argv.silent) ? (function () {}) : console.log,
requestLogger;

if (!argv.s && !argv.silent) {
requestLogger = function(req) {
log('[%s] "%s %s" "%s"', (new Date).toUTCString(), req.method.cyan,     req.url.cyan, req.headers['user-agent']);
}
}
if (!port) {
portfinder.basePort = 8080;
portfinder.getPort(function (err, port) {
if (err) throw err;
listen(port);
});
} else {
listen(port);
}

function listen(port) {
var options = {
root: argv._[0],
cache: argv.c,
showDir: argv.d,
autoIndex: argv.i,
ext: argv.e || argv.ext,
logFn: requestLogger
};

if (argv.cors) {
options.headers = { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' };
}

var server = httpServer.createServer(options);
server.listen(port, host, function() {
log('Starting up http-server, serving '.yellow
  + server.root.cyan
  + ' on port: '.yellow
  + port.toString().cyan);
 log('Hit CTRL-C to stop the server');

if (argv.o) {
  opener('http://127.0.0.1:' + port.toString());
}
});
}

if (process.platform !== 'win32') {
//
// Signal handlers don't work on Windows.
//
process.on('SIGINT', function () {
log('http-server stopped.'.red);
process.exit();
});
}
```

`

Comment: can you just paste your server code / app.js code? Are you using Node.js Express?

Comment: @AlexMills: No, am not using Express. just Node.js

Comment: is firewall blocking requests to your port other than 80?

Comment: No @Sridhar. Firewall isn'tt doing anything. port is free to use.

Comment: what is an 'application url' in this context? May be missed to make an entry in host file for domain?

Comment: url would be http://localhost:8000/app/index.html

Comment: the thing is when i am running the app using bitnami client it is working and running perfectly as it should but when i am running the same app after cloning and all on putty client it is not responding.
The server is running here but on opening the url it shows 'webpage is not available'

Comment: is it 8000 or 8080? you have mentioned both

Comment: @Jack: the default port given in package.json is 8000.So when i run the command `npm start`, the localhost starts at port 8000.. but when i run the command `http-server`,it runs on port 8080.

Answer (score 3):

Please provide some code,
out of pure speculation there may be an issue with bind IP ie. you may have your IP address of server bind to 127.0.0.1 which can only be accessed from locahost, change it to 0.0.0.0 to allow access from outside.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
          'content-type': 'text/plain'
});
res.end('It works');
}).listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');
```

Comment: can u tell me which code do u need to check the issue?

Comment: just the part where you bind your ip and port

Comment: As you may see that i have bound my server to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: there are few possibilities 1) your server isn't actually listening to 8080 or 2) your firewall is blocking the port from outside access. try following commmand : netstat -tupln | grep 8080 , if you get a output then your server is fine the problem may be due to firewall

Comment: Also you could telnet from client side using telnet <ip address> 8080 and see if you get connected

Comment: Soi just checked that the server is listening to 8080 and the firewall is not blocking the port.
after using the command `telnet` i get connected to the server.So there doesn't seem to be any problem here.. :/

Comment: I even turned off the firewall but still see no difference in result.the url is stll not working

Comment: See, i am working in a private domain on putty client. Could this have any effect on the problem that I am facing? i.e. the server not being able to reach the client or vice-versa ?

Comment: I don't think that should be a problem, what about "curl localhost:8000/app/index.html" have you tried this on server?

Comment: yes. it extracts the code inside index.html and displays it in the terminal

Comment: That would suggest that, the problem lies with OS configuration. Can you post netstat ie: "netstat -tupln | grep 8080" output as well and also specify what OS you are using and is your server hosted in AWS?

Comment: The problem is solved.. actually i was running the wrong address constantly that is why the page was not displayed even when the server kept running!

Comment: Thanx for the help anyways.. got to learn a lot of things this way though.. :)

Comment: @NamanGupta I am also facing the same problem. What solved your problem exactly? The server gets started on a port(say 8000) but I could not access it as it says page not found. I have a Ubuntu hosting server with some IP say XX:XX:XX:XX and inside var/www/html/xyz folder I have put the Node project which I am not able to access on the browser with http://XX:XX:XX:XX:8000 URL. What can be the reason?

Comment: Thank you!!! Having 127.0.0.1 or localhost is a problem--an easy mistake to make when copying random code from the internet. 0.0.0.0 works, or just omit it altogether.